# Node.js builtin module readline keeps reading lines after being closed

Tags: node.js, readline

I have following code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {createInterface} = require("readline");
const {join} = require("path");
const {once} = require("events");

async function readMeta (path) {
    const meta = {};
    const rs = fs.createReadStream(path);
    const lineReader = createInterface({input: rs});

    let linesRead = 0;

    lineReader.on("line", line => {

        switch (linesRead) {
            case 0:
                meta.name = line;
                break;
            case 1:
                meta.tags = line.split(" ");
                break;
            case 2:
                meta.type = line;
                break;
            case 3:
                meta.id = +line;
        }

        if (++linesRead === 4) {
            lineReader.close();
        }
    });
    await once(lineReader, "close");
    rs.close();
    return meta;
}
```

It appears to be working, but logging the lines when the `line` event fires reveals otherwise. The event is still being fired after `lineReader.close()` has been called resulting in the whole file being read. I have no idea what is causing this. I found some modules that apparently does the job, but i want do keep the dependencies down if possible.

Comment: better `await once(lineReader, 'end');`  https://github.com/maleck13/readline/blob/master/readline.js#L51 file may not be closed or closed quickly, but Your goal is to catch when it ends reading.

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean, my goal is to make it stop reading, i don't want to read the entire file.

Comment: how about calling `rs.close();` right after `lineReader.close();`cause line reader takes input from read stream which is does not close

Comment: `rs` is being closed when `lineReader` fires it's `close` event.

Comment: please read" https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_close   `Calling rl.close() does not immediately stop other events (including 'line') from being emitted by the readline.Interface instance.`  which means that You've to close read stream first

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling and switching counter I recommend to push lines to array and prevent further push-ing after array size is 4.

Then to call close and after to destructure array to necessary attributes and return object that contains them.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {createInterface} = require("readline");
const {join} = require("path");
const {once} = require("events");

async function readMeta (path) {
    const meta = {};
    const rs = fs.createReadStream(path);
    const lineReader = createInterface({input: rs});

    const linesRead = [];

    lineReader.on("line", line => {
      if (linesRead.length === 4) {
        lineReader.close();
        rs.close();
        return;
      }
      linesRead.push(line.trim());
    });

    await once(lineReader, "close");
    delete rs;
    delete lineReader;

    const [name, tags, type, id] = linesRead;
    return {
      id,
      name,
      type,
      tags: tags.split(' '),
    };
}
```